# tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor with dtype float

Tags: python, types, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and want to train a logistic model for classification.

```
# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([30, 16]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([16]))
train_X, train_Y, X, Y = input('train.csv')

#construct model
pred = model(X, W, b)
# Minimize error using cross entropy
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
# Gradient Descent
learning_rate = 0.1
#optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

training_epochs = 200
batch_size = 300
train_X, train_Y, X, Y = input('train.csv')
acc = []
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 30]) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 16])
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     # Training cycle
     for epoch in range(training_epochs):
         avg_cost = 0.0
         #print(type(y_train[0][0]))
         print(type(train_X))
         print(type(train_X[0][0]))
         print X
         _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: train_X, y: train_Y})
```

The feef_dict method does not work, with the complain:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder_54' with dtype float      [[Node: Placeholder_54 =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]] Caused by op u'Placeholder_54':

I check the data type, for the training feature data X:

```
  train_X type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
  train_X[0][0]: <type 'numpy.float32'>
  train_X size: (300, 30)
  place_holder info : Tensor("Placeholder_56:0", shape=(?, 30), dtype=float32)
```

I do not know why it complains. Hope sb could help, thanks

Comment: If you're in a jupyter notebook, try running `tf.reset_default_graph()` before defining your variables. I was having some similar issues and this was one of the things that helped clear it up.

Answer (score 3):

From your error message, the name of the missing placeholder—`'Placeholder_54'`—is suspicious, because that suggests that at least 54 placeholders have been created in the current interpreter session.

There aren't enough details to say for sure, but I have some suspicions.  Are you running the same code multiple times in the same interpreter session (e.g. using IPython/Jupyter or the Python shell)? Assuming that is the case, I suspect that your `cost` tensor depends on placeholders that were created in a previous execution of that code.

Indeed, your code creates two [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) tensors `x` and `y` **after** building the rest of the model, so it seems likely that either:

1. The missing placeholder was created in a previous execution of this code, or
2. The `input()` function calls `tf.placeholder()` internally and it is these placeholders (perhaps the tensors `X` and `Y`?) that you should be feeding.

Answer (score 1):

I think I came to a similar error. It seems your graph does not have those tensor's x, y on it, you created placeholders with the same names, but that does not mean you got tensor's in your graph with those names.

Here is the link to my question (which I answered my self..): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978848/find-input-tensors-for-protobuf-model)

Use this for getting all the tensors in your graph (pretty useful):

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the code for model() - I bet it defines two placeholders: X is placeholder_56, so where is placeholder_54 coming from?

Then pass the model x,y into the feed_dict, delete your x, y global placeholders, all will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try add graph  `with tf.Graph().as_default():`  to avoid Placeholder redefine when you run jupyter notebook or ipython.