# Find input tensors for protobuf model

Tags: tensorflow

So here is the thing: I am trying to use inference from a model that has been frozen to a .pb (ProtoBuf) file.

I have properly frozen the model selecting the nodes that I am interested to use for inference (just the output). I am also able to select the output tensor but when I input the tensors it gives me an error of the like:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'w2' with dtype float
 [[Node: w2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Here is a simple model that I have frozen:

```
import tensorflow as tf

w1 = tf.placeholder("float", name="w1")

w2 = tf.placeholder("float", name="w2")
b1 = tf.Variable(2.0, name="bias")
feed_dict = {w1: 4, w2: 8}

w3 = tf.add(w1, w2)
w4 = tf.multiply(w3, b1, name="op_to_restore")
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver = tf.train.Saver()

print(sess.run(w4, feed_dict))
# Prints 24 which is sum of (w1+w2)*b1

saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model/test', global_step=1000)
```

And here is the code I am using to do the inference (from a .pb file):

```
w1 = tf.placeholder("float")
w2 = tf.placeholder("float")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("my_test_model/frozen_model.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('op_to_restore:0')
    # sess.run(init)
    print(tensor)
    predictions = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={w1: 4, w2: 8})

print(predictions)
```

Any help will be of great value, thanks!

Comment: If anyone has this issue.. the fix that worked for me was changing the line feed_dict={w1: 4, w2: 8} with feed_dict={'w1:0': 4, 'w2:0': 8}, since this nodes were already created. If you want to print the nodes of your graph the line that gets them is: [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make a clear answer to this question:

If anyone has this issue.. the fix that worked for me was changing the line: `feed_dict={w1: 4, w2: 8}` with `feed_dict={'w1:0': 4, 'w2:0': 8}`, since this nodes were already created. If you want to print the nodes of your graph the line that gets them is:

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```